# Custom layout of UICollectionView in swift 3

Tags: swift3, uicollectionviewlayout, xcode8

I made a custom layout of UICollectionView in xcode8, but my app crashes when I try to view the layout. This is the error I am getting and don't have any idea why this is happening .

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UICollectionView.m:2090
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'the collection view's data source did not return a valid cell from -collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: for index path <NSIndexPath: 0x6080004221e0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}'
```

Also in my CollectionViewLayout file I am returning attributes for the items in the given rect, and the item at the given index path respectively.

```
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        return attributesList
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {

        return attributesList[indexPath.row]
    }
```

Any help is highly appreciated.